# Calculate Lebesgue's integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Calculate the Lebesgue integral of the function

$$ f(x,y)=\left\lbrace\begin{array}{ccl}[x+y]^{2} &\quad&|x|,|y| <12 ,\quad xy \leq 0\\
0 &\quad&\text{otherwise}\end{array} \right.$$

in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Can anyone help with this? I can't find a way to make the expression of $f$ more simply to calculate the integral.

edit: $[\cdot]$ is the integer part.

Comment: In general, we use $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ to denote the floor function. That's "\lfloor" and "\rfloor".

Comment: This function has finite range. It can be integrated by drawing a picture.

Comment: @ncmathsadist: Can you explain this a little more?

Comment: The integrand breaks up into a finite number of cases.  It is piecewise constant on strips between lines of the form $y = a - x$ and $y = a + 1 - x$, where $a$ is an integer.  Draw the slices; the function is constant between the parallel lines that result.  Multiply the area of each strip by the value of the function on the strip.

Comment: The Riemann integral gives the same value (why?)

Comment: @AD.: What's the value of the integral?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Denote
$$
A_{m,n}=\{(x,y):m\leq x<m+1,\quad n\leq y<n+1\}\qquad
a_{mn}=\int_{A_{m,n}}f(x,y)d\mu(x,y)
$$
then
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}f(x,y)d\mu(x,y)=\sum_{(m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}^2}a_{mn}
$$
From definition of $f$ it follows that $a_{mn}\neq 0$
only for pairs $(m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ such that $-N\leq m\leq N-1$, $-N\leq n\leq N-1$ and $mn\leq 0$, because $f$ is non zero only on this sets. Hence
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}f(x,y)d\mu(x,y)=\sum\limits_{m=-N}^{-1}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1}a_{mn}+\sum\limits_{m=0}^{N-1}\sum\limits_{n=-N}^{-1}a_{mn}
$$
It is remains to get the formula for $a_{mn}$. Consider sets
$$
B_{mn}=\{(x,y)\in A_{mn}:x+y<m+n+1\}\qquad C_{mn}=\{(x,y)\in A_{mn}:x+y\geq m+n+1\}
$$
It is easy to see that $A_{mn}=B_{mn}\cup C_{mn}$, $B_{mn}\cap C_{mn}=\varnothing$ and
$$
f(x,y)=(m+n)^2\quad\text{for}\quad(x,y)\in B_{mn}
$$
$$
f(x,y)=(m+n+1)^2\quad\text{for}\quad(x,y)\in C_{mn}
$$
So,
$$
\begin{align}
a_{mn}=\int_{A_{m,n}}f(x,y)d\mu(x,y)
&=\int_{B_{m,n}}f(x,y)d\mu(x,y)+\int_{C_{m,n}}f(x,y)d\mu(x,y)\\
&=(m+n)^2\mu(B_{mn})+(m+n+1)^2\mu(C_{mn})\\
&=\frac{1}{2}(m+n)^2+\frac{1}{2}(m+n+1)^2\\
&=m^2+n^2+2mn+m+n+0.5
\end{align}
$$
Now we can find our integral
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}f(x,y)d\mu(x,y)=\sum_{(m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}^2}a_{mn}=
\left(\sum\limits_{m=-N}^{-1}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1}+\sum\limits_{m=0}^{N-1}\sum\limits_{n=-N}^{-1}\right)(m^2+n^2+2mn+m+n+0.5)
$$
This is a labour computation to get this sum, so we will find it by parts
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\sum\limits_{m=-N}^{-1}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1}+\sum\limits_{m=0}^{N-1}\sum\limits_{n=-N}^{-1}\right)(m^2)
&=\sum\limits_{m=-N}^{-1}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1}m^2+\sum\limits_{m=0}^{N-1}\sum\limits_{n=-N}^{-1}m^2\\
&=N\sum\limits_{m=-N}^{-1}m^2+N\sum\limits_{m=0}^{N-1}m^2\\
&=N\sum\limits_{m=1}^{N}m^2+N\sum\limits_{m=1}^{N-1}m^2\\
&=N\frac{N(N+1)(2N+1)}{6}+N\frac{N(N-1)(2N-1)}{6}\\
&=\frac{2N^4+N^2}{3}\\
\left(\sum\limits_{m=-N}^{-1}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1}+\sum\limits_{m=0}^{N-1}\sum\limits_{n=-N}^{-1}\right)(m)
&=\sum\limits_{m=-N}^{-1}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1}m+\sum\limits_{m=0}^{N-1}\sum\limits_{n=-N}^{-1}m\\
&=N\sum\limits_{m=-N}^{-1}m+N\sum\limits_{m=0}^{N-1}m\\
&=N\sum\limits_{n=-N}^{N-1}m=N\cdot(-N)=-N^2
\end{align}
$$
Similarly,
$$
\left(\sum\limits_{m=-N}^{-1}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1}+\sum\limits_{m=0}^{N-1}\sum\limits_{n=-N}^{-1}\right)(n^2)=\frac{2N^4+N^2}{3}
$$
$$
\left(\sum\limits_{m=-N}^{-1}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1}+\sum\limits_{m=0}^{N-1}\sum\limits_{n=-N}^{-1}\right)(n)=-N^2
$$
Then
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\sum\limits_{m=-N}^{-1}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1}+\sum\limits_{m=0}^{N-1}\sum\limits_{n=-N}^{-1}\right)(mn)
&=\sum\limits_{m=-N}^{-1}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1}mn+\sum\limits_{m=0}^{N-1}\sum\limits_{n=-N}^{-1}mn\\
&=\sum\limits_{m=-N}^{-1}m\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1}n+\sum\limits_{m=0}^{N-1}m\sum\limits_{n=-N}^{-1}n\\
&=-\sum\limits_{m=1}^{N}m\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1}n-\sum\limits_{m=0}^{N-1}m\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}n\\
&=-\frac{N(N+1)}{2}\frac{N(N-1)}{2}-\frac{N(N-1)}{2}\frac{N(N+1)}{2}\\
&=-\frac{N^2(N^2-1)}{2}\\
\left(\sum\limits_{m=-N}^{-1}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1}+\sum\limits_{m=0}^{N-1}\sum\limits_{n=-N}^{-1}\right)(0.5)
&=\sum\limits_{m=-N}^{-1}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1}0.5+\sum\limits_{m=0}^{N-1}\sum\limits_{n=-N}^{-1}0.5\\
&=0.5N^2+0.5N^2\\
&=N^2
\end{align}
$$
Finally, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}f(x,y)d\mu(x,y)
&=\left(\sum\limits_{m=-N}^{-1}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1}+\sum\limits_{m=0}^{N-1}\sum\limits_{n=-N}^{-1}\right)(m^2+n^2+2mn+m+n+0.5)\\
&=\frac{2N^4+N^2}{3}+\frac{2N^4+N^2}{3}-2\frac{N^2(N^2-1)}{2}-N^2-N^2+N^2\\
&=\frac{N^4+2N^2}{3}
\end{align}
$$
If we take $N=12$ we will obtain $7008$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

1. The function is non-negative, and hence one may apply Tonelli's theorem (sometimes cited as Fubini-Tonelli's or even Fubini' theorem).
2. Draw the domain of integration (that is the set where $f(x,y)\ne0$). Split up the domain in order to adopt step 1.

Comment: Кого я вижу! Ты ушел с dxdy?

Comment: @Norbert What do you mean?

Comment: May be I've confused you with my friend from MSU. Artem is it you?

Comment: @Norbert Sorry that is not me. :)

Comment: What a nuisance... The reason of this confusion is that he have the same nick and the same range of mathematical interests as yours!

Comment: @Norbert Sounds like a nice fellow!